# How can I count the frequency of repeated values in dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe that is

```
UC      WR
V001    A, B, C, nan, A, C, D
C001    nan, C, D, A, nan, A
C002    C, B, B, A, A, A
C003    A, C, A, C, B, nan
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm not able to get rid of the `nan`s. From this column, I want to have a different column, or a dictionary that gives me the frequency count of the different values in `WR`.

```
UC     WR Count
V001  {A: 2, B:1, C:2, D:1}
C001  {A:2, C:1, D:1}
C002  {A:3, B:2, C:1}
C003  {A:2, B:1, C:2}
```

or a similar dictionary. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do not make the `dict` into the cell in `pandas`, which will make a lots of build-in `pandas`' nice function not work any more

```
df.set_index('UC').WR.\
 str.split(', ',expand=True).\
    stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).drop('nan',1)
      A  B  C  D
UC              
V001  2  1  2  1
C001  2  0  1  1
C002  3  2  1  0
C003  2  1  2  0
```

Answer (score 3):

At first ignoring the `nan` entries, my approach would be:

```
df['WR Count'] = df.WR.str.replace(' ', '').str.split(',').apply(Counter)

#                          WR                                    WR Count
# UC                                                                                                        
# V001  A, B, C, nan, A, C, D  {'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'nan': 1, 'D': 1}                               
# C001   nan, C, D, A, nan, A          {'nan': 2, 'C': 1, 'D': 1, 'A': 2}                               
# C002       C, B, B, A, A, A                    {'C': 1, 'B': 2, 'A': 3}                           
# C003     A, C, A, C, B, nan          {'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'nan': 1}
```

Note that if you are sure that the separator is *always*  `', '`, then you can hardcode it, which leads to a shorter command:

```
df['WR Count'] = df.WR.str.split(', ').apply(Counter)
```

Comment: I think you could directly split by `', '` with a comma and a space, instead of first replacing the space and then split on the comma

Comment: You are right. I kind of automatically made it this way because of so many datasets I saw here that have arbitrary numbers of spaces inbetween... But normally you should be able to rely on some automated pattern, so I'll edit by adding this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values as dictionaries you may also try:

```
df['WR Count'] = df['WR'].apply(lambda x: dict(Counter(x.split(', ')))
```